# skflow with Docker images gets learn.datasets not imported error

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I set the docker image with Dockerfile below.

```
FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install scikit-learn
RUN pip install scipy
RUN pip install pandas
```

I am using Pycharm and set the remote Docker tf library.

The below file runs with an error which says ' AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets' '

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cc9bfbf8ef4a3dea6514ad939d238f7442188247/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_cnn.py
```

Do I have to compile some source codes before running the test code, or can I not run the code in Windows? Below is the error messages.

```
f58474f68f97:python -u /opt/project/examples/skflow/text_classification_cnn.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/examples/skflow/text_classification_cnn.py", line 30, in <module>
    dbpedia = learn.datasets.load_dataset('dbpedia')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your TensorFlow to latest version. That docker image is probably outdated.